# Rotate each letter of a text individually

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm using a plug (Simple Side Tab - https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-side-tab/) in my wordpress page that put a text in the side. This text is roated using "transform: rotate(-90deg)". The problem is that I want the text to be like:

> E
>
> X
>
> A
>
> M
>
> P
>
> L
>
> E

How can I do that in jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a combination between `width` and `word-wrap`:

```css
p {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 1px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<p>EXAMPLE</p>
```